# How to change and save with replicated model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an model. I have tried to replicate it.

I want to change some attributes of the model and then save to DB.

ex:

```
$clone_journey_item = $journey_content->replicate();
$clone_journey_item->activation_dt = $clone_item->activation_dt;// 2020-05-20 00:00:00
$clone_journey_item->save();
dump($clone_journey_item->activation_dt); 
//$clone_journey_item->activation_dt = 2019-08-19 00:00:00
```

Why does it takes old value of model? I couldn't save a new value.

Comment: What is your activation_dt column type? Is is fillable?

Answer (score 3):

`save()` won't work for replicated item. 
use `push()`.

```
$clone_journey_item->push();
```